Salesforce getContentAsPDF return NULL
Answer:
I tried to track all the logs.
If I make calls to individual methods - everything works, the process of converting to PDF does not work
I spent many pages of search to find the answer:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000392426&type=1

I have logic in a trigger that should create PDF files and send them via email:
    @Future(Callout=true) // never change (U can't generate PDF from trigger).
private static void startPdfGeneration(Id opportunityId) {
    List<Opportunity> opportunities = [
        SELECT Id, Quote_Number__c, Name, Owner.Email, Owner.ManagerId, Owner.Manager.Email
        FROM Opportunity
        WHERE Id = :opportunityId
        LIMIT 1
    ];
    PageReference pdfPage = Page.TestPdf;
    pdfPage.getParameters().put('id', opportunityId);

    Blob pdfBlob;
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {

        pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContentAsPDF();
    } else {
        pdfBlob = Blob.valueOf('Mock PDF Content');
    }

    Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
    attachment.ParentId = opportunityId;
    attachment.Name = 'Quote-' + opportunities.get(0).Quote_Number__c + '-PDF.pdf';
    attachment.Body = pdfBlob;
    attachment.ContentType = 'application/pdf';

    insert attachment;

    sendPdfInEmail(attachment, opportunities.get(0));
}

the method itself works on the System Administrator profile,
but does not work on others, giving an empty (absolutely empty PDF)
Important:
Accesses to the class - issued
Accesses to the vf page - issued
I used constructor with params, to check if something inside crashes - no, everything works correctly.
What could be the reason?
pdf part:
<apex:page controller="TestPdfController"
    showHeader="true"
       setup="true"
       sidebar="false"
       standardStylesheets="false"
       renderAs="pdf"
       applyBodyTag="false">

<head>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
        @page {
            padding-top: 315px;
            margin-top: 5px;
            @top-center {
                content: element(header);
            }
            @bottom-center {
                content: element(footer);
            }
        }

        .pagenumber:before {
            content: counter(page);
        }
        .pagecount:before {
            content: counter(pages);
        }

        .content {
            width: 710px;
        }

        .header {
            height: 310px;
            position: running(header);
            top: 0;
            padding-left: 8px;
            width: 710px;
            border: 1px blueviolet solid;

        }

        .header td {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .header td:first-child {
            width: 25%;
        }

        .header td:nth-child(2) {
            width: 40%;
        }

        .header td:last-child {
            width: 25%;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

...

</apex:page>
apex controller:
public without sharing class TestPdfController {
constants...
public TestPdfController() {
String recordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    List<Opportunity> opportunities = selectOpportunity(recordId);
    if (opportunities.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    Opportunity opportunity = opportunities.get(0);
    quoteNumber = opportunity.Quote_Number__c;
    totalAmount = opportunity.Amount;
    validUntil = convertDateToString(opportunity.GI_Quote_Valid_Until__c);
    today = convertDateToString(Date.today());
    pentaxRep = getFullName(opportunity.Owner.FirstName, opportunity.Owner.LastName);
    deliveryTerms = opportunity.Delivery_Terms__c;
    paymentTerms = opportunity.GI_Payment_Terms__c;
    //TODO: addRealMapping
    pentaxCSR = 'hardcode pentaxCSR';
    estimatedTaxes = 0.0;

    if (String.isNotBlank(opportunity.AccountId)) {
        accountName = opportunity.Account.Name;
        accountNumber = opportunity.Account.AccountNumber;

        accountAddressLine1 = opportunity.Account.ShippingStreet;
        accountAddressLine1 = String.isNotBlank(accountAddressLine1) ? accountAddressLine1.toUpperCase() : accountAddressLine1;

        List<String> line2 = new List<String>();
        if (String.isNotBlank(opportunity.Account.ShippingCity)) { line2.add(opportunity.Account.ShippingCity); }
        if (String.isNotBlank(opportunity.Account.ShippingState)) { line2.add(opportunity.Account.ShippingState); }
        if (String.isNotBlank(opportunity.Account.ShippingPostalCode)) { line2.add(opportunity.Account.ShippingPostalCode); }

        accountAddressLine2 = String.join(line2, ', ');
        accountAddressLine2 = String.isNotBlank(accountAddressLine2) ? accountAddressLine2.toUpperCase() : accountAddressLine2;

        accountAddressLine3 = opportunity.Account.ShippingCountry;
        accountAddressLine3 = String.isNotBlank(accountAddressLine3) ? accountAddressLine3.toUpperCase() : accountAddressLine3;

        accountAddressLine1Flag = String.isNotBlank(accountAddressLine1) && (String.isNotBlank(accountAddressLine2) || String.isNotBlank(accountAddressLine3));
        if (accountAddressLine1Flag) {
            accountAddressLine1 += ',';
        }
        accountAddressLine2Flag = String.isNotBlank(accountAddressLine1) && String.isNotBlank(accountAddressLine2) && String.isNotBlank(accountAddressLine3);
        if (accountAddressLine2Flag) {
            accountAddressLine2 += ',';
        }

        accountShippingAddress = generateFullAddressFromList(
            opportunity.Account.ShippingStreet,
            opportunity.Account.ShippingCity,
            opportunity.Account.ShippingState,
            opportunity.Account.ShippingPostalCode,
            opportunity.Account.ShippingCountry
        );

        //TODO: check bloc and filling

        List<String> nameList = new List<String>();
        nameList.add(opportunity.Primary_Contact__r.FirstName);
        nameList.add(opportunity.Primary_Contact__r.LastName);
        contactName = String.join(nameList, ' ');
        contactPhone = opportunity.Primary_Contact__r.Phone;
        contactEmail = opportunity.Primary_Contact__r.Email;
        contactFax = opportunity.Primary_Contact__r.Fax;
    }


    //block 2: work with Opp Line Items
    subtotalsList = 0;
    subtotalsDiscount = 0;
    subtotalsExtended = 0;

    List<OpportunityLineItem> items = selectAllOppLineItems(recordId);
    itemsArray = new List<TestPdfController.ProductWrapper>();
    for (OpportunityLineItem item : items) {
        ProductWrapper lineWrapper = new ProductWrapper();
        lineWrapper.model = item.ProductCode.replace('--', '\n--');
        lineWrapper.qty = item.Quantity;
        lineWrapper.listPerUnit = item.ListPrice;
        lineWrapper.contractPerUnit = item.UnitPrice;
        lineWrapper.discountPerUnit = item.Discount__c;
        lineWrapper.extended = item.TotalPrice;

        if (String.isNotBlank(item.Product2Id)) {
            lineWrapper.description = item.Product2.Description;
        }

        itemsArray.add(lineWrapper);

        subtotalsList += (item.Quantity * item.ListPrice);
        subtotalsDiscount += (item.Quantity * item.Discount__c);
        subtotalsExtended += item.TotalPrice;
    }

    //block 3 notes
    notes = opportunity.Quote_Notes__c;
    notes2 = opportunity.Additional_Quote_Notes__c;
}

}

can the used VF page be opened in browser by the respective user?

yes, if U open by any user and use correct link - you can see normal PDF
....sandbox.vf.force.com/apex/TestPdf?Id=006V9000002MIV0IAO

That might come from your visual force page / controller.
can you post the code also ?

I removed all the logic from the constructor and it still doesn't work, I left only the locked text

Similar construction works for me for ~80 different orgs for ~10 years, so there is no problem in approach. Must be a mistake in code or permissions.
Or maybe it is due to https://status.salesforce.com/incidents/13231 but it must impact the whole environment

I add code block for check

Have you checked the debug log to see what your queries return when a non-admin user runs it?

Answer:
I tried to track all the logs.
If I make calls to individual methods - everything works, the process of converting to PDF does not work
I spent many pages of search to find the answer:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000392426&type=1
